# cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string'

Tags: c#

Question answered many times, but I don't know how to solve this !

```
    string path = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem).Substring(0, 1) + (":\\");
    var ext = new List<string> { ".tmp", ".vbs", ".lnk" }
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        if (file.EndsWith(ext,  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ext);
        }
```

Comment: "EndsWith" require a string as a first parameter. You are passing a list of strings

Comment: Which line has the error? I mean I can guess, but...

Comment: `"*" + ext` just won't work - how is this error confusing?

Comment: the error under "ext" in  if (file.EndsWith(ext, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
var extensions = new List<string> { ".tmp", ".vbs", ".lnk" }
foreach (string ext in extensions) {
  foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
    if (file.EndsWith(ext, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
      MessageBox.Show(ext);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks that's works fine !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
if (ext.Any(x => file.EndsWith(x))
    MessageBox.Show(ext);
```

Comment: the same error in 
File.Delete(ext);

Comment: If you are expecting to use a Delete function you should put it in the question. The code that I provided works for the context you asked

Comment: your code works fine 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate extensions:

```
    var extensions = new List<string> { ".tmp", ".vbs", ".lnk" };

    foreach (var ext in extensions) {

        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories)) 
        {
            if (file.EndsWith(ext, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                 MessageBox.Show(ext);
            }
       }
   }
```